# Asp.net repeater in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

How can I use a repeater in javascript tag? I am trying to implement map using longitude and latitude from sql database.
Following this tutorial http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Google-Maps-using-Latitude-and-Longitude-in-ASPNet.aspx

And this shows errors like syntax error, expected ']' and expected '/'

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var markers = [
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
             {
                 "title": '<%# Eval("senderName") %>',
                 "lat": '<%# Eval("senderLattitude") %>',
                 "lng": '<%# Eval("senderLongitude") %>'
             }
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,   
        </SeparatorTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    ];
   </script>
```

Comment: What does the code the browser sees look like?

Comment: What if senderName happens to have a quote in it? This approach won't work well. Instead, you should convert all your data to JSON on the server, then embed it on the client. Create a function in your code behind like `public string GetMarkerJson(){}` and then call it on the with `<%: GetMarkerJson() />` (my syntax on that might be slightly off), no repeater necessary.